# Using powermockito to mock a static method. What am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: powermockito

I want to use powermock to state a static method on a class (fragment of class below):

```
public class TestService<T> {
    public static <T> TestService<T> function1(Class<T> rawType, Object id) {
```

The relevant portion of the test class is listed below. While setting up the mock, if I explicitly set a value for the integer parameter, then call with that same value, everything works as expected. The call to function1 returns the testServiceProxy.

However, what I want to do is return that value no matter what value of the integer is passed in. To do this I comment out the first line:

```
// PowerMockito.when(TestService.function1(Subscription.class,id)).thenReturn(testServiceProxy);
```

and remove the comments from the second line.

**After doing this, the calls to function1 return null.**

Why??

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestService.class)
public class TestServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    private TestService<Subscription> testServiceProxy;
        
    @Mock
    private Subscription subscription;

    @Test
    public void testStart() throws Exception {
        Integer id = new Integer(5);
        
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestService.class);
        PowerMockito.when(TestService.getString()).thenReturn("Hello!");
        PowerMockito.when(testServiceProxy.getInt()).thenReturn(new Integer(15));
        
        PowerMockito.when(TestService.function1(Subscription.class,id)).thenReturn(testServiceProxy);
     //   PowerMockito.when(TestService.function1(Subscription.class,Matchers.eq(any(Integer.class)))).thenReturn(testServiceProxy);

        System.out.println("String: " + TestService.getString());
        System.out.println("TestServiceProxy: "+testServiceProxy);
//      id = new Integer(6);
        System.out.println("Function1: "+TestService.function1(Subscription.class, id));
        TestService<Subscription>  foo = TestService.function1(Subscription.class, id);
        if (foo != null) {
            System.out.println(" foo instrumentId: "+foo.getInt());
            System.out.println(" subselect instrumentId: "+testServiceProxy.getInt());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Foo is null");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After further work, I've come to understand that you can't be specific about one value and specify any for another.

Also I needed to use the Mockito class to ensure that the correct functions where being called.

```
PowerMockito.when(TestService.function1(Mockito.any(Class.class), Mockito.any(String.class))).thenReturn(testServiceProxy);
```

This method call correctly sets up the mocks to be used in my test case.